# App Group ID and initWithSuiteName: method

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, today-extension, ios-app-group, appgroups

I have to use App Group to communicate with my container app and Today Widget. I've created App Group ID like `group.com.myCompany.myApp` and using it in code like this:   `NSUserDefaults *shared = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.myCompany.myApp"];` And all works great.
The problem is - for enterprise and AppStore I need to create another App Group ID and AppID and so on - does this mean that I have to change every time, when I build ipa for Debug/Enterprise/AppStore, this part `@"group.com.myCompany.myApp"` to `@"group.com.myCompanyEnterprise.myApp"` and `@"group.com.myCompanyAppStore.myApp"` manually accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create new `App Group ID` and `AppID` for `enterprise` and `AppStore`. Just proceeds with same `AppID`. All you need to change in build of `enterprise` and `AppStore` is `provisioning profile` and respective production certificate. That should be access with same `AppID`. So, no need to change `App Group ID` and `AppID` every time.

Comment: But there is no my App Group ID that I created for Dev in the list of them, when logged in Enterprise program